# How to insertInto() without setting values and return the newly created ID?

Tags: java, jooq

How can I insert a record without specifying any values ans just return the newly created ID? If I do it like this:

```
private Long createOffer() {

    return this.ctx.insertInto(StoreOffer.STORE_OFFER, StoreOffer.Store_OFFER.ID)
            .returning(StoreOffer.STORE_OFFER.ID)
            .fetchOne().getValue(StoreOffer.STORE_OFFER.ID);
}
```

I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. If I just set it `null` the *Not-Null-Constraint* gets triggered..

```
private Long createOffer() {

    return this.ctx.insertInto(StoreOffer.STORE_OFFER, StoreOffer.Store_OFFER.ID)
            .values((Long)null)
            .returning(StoreOffer.STORE_OFFER.ID)
            .fetchOne().getValue(StoreOffer.STORE_OFFER.ID);
}
```

I also tried this:

```
private Long createOffer() {
    StoreOfferRecord storeOfferRecord = this.ctx.newRecord(StoreOffer.STORE_OFFER);
    storeOfferRecord.store();
    return storeOfferRecord.getId();
}
```

but the ID is always `null`.

---

The table `store_offer` is currently just looking like this:

```
CREATE TABLE store_offer (

    -- PRIMARY KEY

    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Comment: why do you need this? standard approach is to insert actual row and only then get its ID

Comment: @Lashane Well, I only want to insert an actual row and get the newly auto-generated ID for further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using `INSERT INTO .. DEFAULT VALUES`

jOOQ supports the SQL standard `DEFAULT VALUES` clause on `INSERT` statements for this use-case:

```
return this.ctx.insertInto(StoreOffer.STORE_OFFER)
               .defaultValues()
               .returning(StoreOffer.STORE_OFFER.ID)
               .fetchOne().getValue(StoreOffer.STORE_OFFER.ID);
```

See also: 
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-default-values/

#### Why you got a `NullPointerException`

You were able to write the following query [because of an API flaw (#3771)](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3771). The following is not supposed to even compile:

```
return this.ctx.insertInto(StoreOffer.STORE_OFFER, StoreOffer.Store_OFFER.ID)
               .returning(StoreOffer.STORE_OFFER.ID)
               .fetchOne().getValue(StoreOffer.STORE_OFFER.ID);
```

#### Why `record.store()` didn't work:

jOOQ records have an internal per-column changed flag. There is no record-level changed flag that would indicate that the whole record needs to be sent to the database, even without any changes. Specifically, this wouldn't make any sense if an `UPDATE` statement would need to be issued.

Comment: @StefanFalk: Sure, no worries :)

Answer (score -2):

You can try `new Long(0)` instead of `(Long)null`

Comment: That cast does look weird, but it is necessary because `values()` is an overloaded method and the Java compiler cannot decide for a most specific method when passing the `null` literal. In any case, this didn't provoke the `NullPointerException`